# change sqlite table column to be unique

Tags: android, sqlite, android-database

I have a table in my db like this :

```
. . .

 String contactsTableName = TABLE_CONTACTS;

            // creating the "contacts" table
            buf.append("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ");
            buf.append(contactsTableName);
            buf.append(" (");
            buf.append("_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,");
            buf.append("username TEXT,");
            buf.append("nickname TEXT,");

            buf.append("provider INTEGER,");
            buf.append("account INTEGER,");
            buf.append("contactList INTEGER,");
            buf.append("type INTEGER,");
            buf.append("subscriptionStatus INTEGER,");
            buf.append("subscriptionType INTEGER,");
. . .
```

And now i want to change this table and make `username` column `UNIQUE`, I wrote the `onUpgrade()` method i don’t know how is sql syntax for this purpose.
I change this code like this in my `onCreate()` :

```
buf.append("username TEXT UNIQUE");
```

I hope i explain my problem clear and apologise for my poor English. :)

Comment: seems ok as `username TEXT unique` will run. did you see any error. Also first empty all the data and remove the line `username TEXT` wrote earlier

Comment: Its not my app first release and i dont want users lost their data! its ok for new user but for users upgrade their app its a problem

Comment: i asked about the error you see. is there any? put the error logs.

changing the column as unique may cause issue if any duplicate value is already there.

Comment: The problem is im not sure how can i write an alter statment for changing column

Comment: you are changing type which seems ok. so go with it and if any error occurs let us know